Should I use a partially or fully threaded screw?
I am building a wooden ladder. I am attaching/securing the rungs to the rails using screws only (two 1/8 steel screws on each side). I know this is a design for failure, but my question has more of a technical nature than practical. Also assume the rungs are made of hardwood such as oak, and the rails are made of a softer wood.
In this hypothetical project, should I use a partially or fully threaded screw? And why? (Or maybe it won't make any significant difference?) Also any recommended screw head type, e.g, countersink vs domed head vs flat, etc.?


A drawing of your ladder and how you are attaching the rungs would be helpful.

Added a photo .

We actually have a previous Question that at first glance seems to pretty much answer this,
Are there specific types of screws I should use for woodworking?
Except that conventional "wood screws" of the old type are now less common, and good to very good modern screws can have threading over their entire length which changes the picture in terms of recommendations. These screws can be so superior that there's no good reason NOT to use them.

In this hypothetical project, should one use a partially or fully threaded screw?

Yes :-) As long as the screw is up to the task it doesn't matter whether it's fully or partially threaded, as long as one uses it appropriately.
Note carefully the clearance hole, not just desirable but nearly mandatory if using a screw threaded over its entire length; and it needs to be larger than it would be otherwise.
Where a screw is partially threaded but passes through a board much thicker than typical the unthreaded portion can be shorter than needed, so the same type of larger clearance hole needs to be used as well. OR one uses counterboring, where the head of the screw sits well below the surface. Counterbores are also useful in using shorter screws than would otherwise be required.
Even though it's linked to in the above-linked Answer since the strength of screws driven in to end grain is so intrinsic to this design I'll link to the this here as well,
Endgrain screw withdrawal force

Also any recommended screw head type?

Not Phillips ^_^
Although I'm not kidding this is covered more seriously in the Answer linked at top, but note that you're often constrained in what head is available for a given screw type. In other words if you want to use screw X it comes with head Y so that's what you're using.

I have grown an extremely strong dislike for the Phillips head screw. However, when hanging drywall, I used Phillips head screws because that's all that's available in a drywall screw and it's 100% the best option for the job precisely because of the feature of the Phillips head that I dislike for all other applications. ;)

@graphus, thank you for your answer.

You referred to "very good modern screws". Does an A2 stainless steel screw (size M4) fall in this category, so that as you said partial or full thread would not make any difference?
When referring to pilot hole, you mentioned: "and it needs to be larger than it would be otherwise". Could you clarify larger than what? When using an M4 screw (2.5mm solid round body + 1.5mm for threads on both sides), wouldn't a 2.5mm drill bit do the job?
Obviously, these still refer to applications similar to the one in the main question.


@Ben Note that pilot hole (goes into the ladder steps) and clearance hole (goes into the ladder sides) are not the same thing! “larger” was in reference to the latter. The first linked answer has an image that illustrates the two holes well.

@Ben, please note for the future that Comments are not for separate queries — if something is worth asking it's really worth having its own Q (assuming you can't find the answer for yourself, especially here on Woodworking since there's a global rule about no duplicates on SE). 1) Why stainless? If it's because of the oak put your worries aside, stainless fasteners are not required for oak. Plus, there are better fasteners in materials other than SS. Also, why so small? Always worth bumping up the size if strength is required (in addition to going longer, for a belt-and-braces approach).


clearance hole, not pilot. Size the clearance hole to the "major diameter" of the screw you're using — thread diameter, then add a smidge. If you don't have a large set of bits with incremental sizes (as most of us don't) it's OK to just wallow out an exact-size drilled hole by running the spinning bit up and down a few times, even gently leaning the bit to the side.


Re: stainless… I’ve had variable results, where some ss screws are great and others break. (Breakage is probably due to pushing the limits with pre drilling.) Unless you need stainless, I wouldn’t risk it.

@AloysiusDefenestrate, the tendency towards breakage issues is one of the consistent cautions I've heard about stainless fasteners. This is across the board, but especially from those who have to use them a lot (e.g. in Accoya and for oak in exterior applications).

@AloysiusDefenestrate, I am no wood worker, but my research indicates that next up from stainless steal screw is 410 steel, but it looks like using 410 is more suitable for metals, and would be pushing it too far for wood. I read about a few 300 series steel screws too, but as far as bearing weight, it seems they are all about at the same level. I would use 4 stainless steel A2 grade screws. For going up and down the ladder several times a day by a slow and at most a 200 lbs person, I think it would be fine.

As for partially Vs. fully threaded, as @Graphus indicated, it does not look like there would be much difference in this type of application. Of course then there is the screw head type (domed, countersink, flat, etc.). To make it more complicated, there is fine threaded (hardwood) vs. coarse (softwood). The rail is softwood and the rung is hardwood. Bottom line, there are too many parameters and no clear answers. I have even called wood workers/cabinet makers, and I get opposite answers. I'll go with A2 stainless steel coarse fully threaded screws.
